# How to read lines with comments # in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I’m using a ‘FlatFileItemReader’ to process a file. I would like to read a line with # as well. Currently, it just skips the lines.

Answer (score 5):

[FlatFileItemReader](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.java) by default use # as a comment character. So any line starts with # will be skipped.

private String[] comments = new String[] { "#" };

If you want to read this then set below method to whatever comment character you want.

[public void setComments(java.lang.String[] comments)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html#setComments-java.lang.String:A-)

or set empty string array if you do not have any comment character.

Comment: Do u mean that I would have to extend the `FlatFileItemReader` and override the `setComments` method?

Comment: No, just call `yourWriter.setComments(new String[]);` or the equivalent in XML if using XML configuration.